# Convert from scientific to decimal after removing extra characters in R

Tags: r, csv, gsub

This should be really simple and I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm running into issues when converting from scientific to decimal notation in R - looks like the E-04 is being removed, so the numbers are magnitudes larger than they should be. I'm reading in a csv using `read.csv(df, stringasfactors = FALSE)` and have fractional hours in this `df$time`:

```
df$time
4.3138888888888887E-4h
0.833h
4.2583333333333335E-4h
```

My current code is:

```
df$time<-gsub('h','',df$time)
df$time<- as.numeric(df$time)
```

which gives me

```
df$time
4.3138
0.833
4.2583
```

Anybody have any thoughts? Would have included reproducible data but couldn't producing a character vector (only factors).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out - earlier in the code, I applied a `substr(df$time, 10)` which in turn did not include the E for some of the entries.

Removing that, and it works fine.

Please learn from my mistake!